# How do I write in Hebrew for a Ketubah, "On the first day of the week, the thirtieth day of Adar I in the year fifty-seven seventy one"

Tags: marriage, hebrew, calendar

How do I write in Hebrew for a Ketubah, "On the first day of the week, the thirtieth day of Adar I in the year fifty-seven seventy one"?

Question was asked by Stephen Spiegel, I'm just posting it here as its own question instead of a comment.

Comment: Who is Stephen Spiegel?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a leap year (i.e. there's both Adar I and Adar II),

> בראשון בשבת שלושים יום לחדש אדר הראשון שהוא ראש חודש לאדר השני שנת חמשת אלפים ושבע מאות ושבעים ואחד

Comment: Why wouldn't we write באחד בשבת like by Gittin (ShA EH 126:3)?